# Some charts do not appear when using GridSpec of Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This is my pandas DataFrame:

```
Area     Gender Amount
XXX      Men    23495
YYY      Men    9336
ZZZ      Men    8828
TTT      Men    11546
XXX      Women  19798
YYY      Women  8235
ZZZ      Women  9122
TTT      Women  10800
```

This is my code to plot multiple charts:

```
import pandas as pd
import bumpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_men = df[df["Gender"]=="Men"].drop("Gender", axis=1)
df_women = df[df["Gender"]=="Women"].drop("Gender", axis=1)

men_labels = df_men.Area.values
men_counts = df_men.Quantity.values

women_labels = df_women.Area.values
women_counts = df_women.Quantity.values

plt.figure(1, figsize=(20,10))
the_grid = GridSpec(2, 2)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('coolwarm')
colors = [cmap(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, 8)]

plt.subplot(the_grid[0, 0], aspect=1, title='Men')
_ = plt.pie(men_counts, labels=men_labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, colors=colors)

plt.subplot(the_grid[0, 1], aspect=1, title='Women')
_ = plt.pie(women_counts, labels=women_labels, autopct='%.0f%%', shadow=True, colors=colors)

plt.subplot(the_grid[1, 0], aspect=1, title='Men')
sns.barplot(x='Quantity', y='Area', data=df_men, palette='coolwarm')

plt.subplot(the_grid[1, 1], aspect=1, title='Women')
sns.barplot(x='Quantity', y='Area', data=df_women, palette='coolwarm')

plt.show()
```

The problem is that the plots of the 2nd row are not shown correctly. They seem to be flattened and no bars are visible. If I plot these charts separately, they are drawn well.
What is wrong in my code?

This does not work:

```
plt.subplot(the_grid[1, 1], aspect=1, title='Women')
sns.barplot(x='Quantity', y='Area', data=df_women, palette='coolwarm')
```

But this works:

```
sns.barplot(x='Quantity', y='Area', data=df_women, palette='coolwarm')
```

**UPDATE:**

This is the output of `df.to_dict()`.

```
{'Amount': {0: 23495,
  1: 9336,
  2: 8828,
  3: 11546,
  4: 19798,
  5: 8235,
  6: 9122,
  7: 10800},
 'Gender': {0: 'Men',
  1: 'Men',
  2: 'Men',
  3: 'Men',
  4: 'Women',
  5: 'Women',
  6: 'Women',
  7: 'Women'},
 'Area': {0: 'XXX',
  1: 'YYY',
  2: 'ZZZ',
  3: 'TTT',
  4: 'XXX',
  5: 'YYY',
  6: 'ZZZ',
  7: 'TTT'}}
```

Comment: Please share `df.to_dict()`

Comment: @user32185: Please see my update.

Comment: @user32185: the output is empty.

Comment: @user32185: The problem is that when I use this line `plt.subplot(the_grid[1, 1], aspect=1, title='Women')`, I cannot draw the plots in the 2nd row. Why it is not reproducible? Does it work for you? It does not work for me on 2 laptops. The dataset is exactly what I have.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer myself. 
The solution was to delete `aspect=1`:

```
plt.subplot(the_grid[1, 1], aspect=1, title='Women')
```

This works:

```
plt.subplot(the_grid[1, 1], title='Women')
sns.barplot(x='Quantity', y='Area', data=df_women, palette='coolwarm')
```